# How can I add a vertical line to a seaborn dist plot where it picks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

How can I add a vertical line at the x-location in which y is on its maximum in a seaborn dist plot?

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(5000)
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde = False)
```

PS_ In the example above, we know that it's probably going to pick at `0`. I am interested to know how I can find this value in general, for any given distribution of x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to get a more accurate point. First get the smooth distribution function, use it to extract the maxima, and then remove it.

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(5000)
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde = True)

x = ax.lines[0].get_xdata()
y = ax.lines[0].get_ydata()
plt.axvline(x[np.argmax(y)], color='red')
ax.lines[0].remove()
```

[image]

**Edit** Alternate solution without using `kde=True`

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(5000)
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde = False)

kde = stats.gaussian_kde(x) # Compute the Gaussian KDE
idx = np.argmax(kde.pdf(x)) # Get the index of the maximum
plt.axvline(x[idx], color='red') # Plot a vertical line at corresponding x
```

This results in the actual distribution and not the density values

[image]