# How can I add vertical lines to a seaborn dist plots where they pick? [multiple distributions in single plot]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Using the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600828/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-seaborn-dist-plot-where-it-picks) I could generate the dist plot as I needed. However, when I want to apply the same solution to multiple plots, it doesn't seem to work as expected. I am seeking for proposed solutions. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
data01 = np.random.normal(10, 5, 1000)
data02 = np.random.normal(20, 5, 1000)

ax1 = sns.distplot(data01, color = 'blue', kde = True)

x1 = ax1.lines[0].get_xdata()
y1 = ax1.lines[0].get_ydata()
plt.axvline(x1[np.argmax(y1)], color='blue')

ax2 = sns.distplot(data02, color = 'red', kde = True)

x2 = ax2.lines[0].get_xdata()
y2 = ax2.lines[0].get_ydata()
plt.axvline(x2[np.argmax(y2)], color='red')

plt.legend()
```

Here is what I get, which is not what I expected (two vertical lines, one for each):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct index: Index `0` is for the blue kde, index `1` is for the blue vertical line, index `2` is for the red kde.

Intuitively, as the name suggests `ax2.lines` gives you the collection of **all the lines** on the current figure. When you plot `distplot` with `kde=True` the second time, you already have 2 lines (previous kde and vertical line) so the index of the second kde is `2` because indexing starts from 0 in python. This is because you are working with the same figure object so the artists plotted from `ax1` will also be carried over to `ax2`. On the contrary, if you were to have individual subplots, then you would have used the same index `0` for both

```
ax1 = sns.distplot(data01, color = 'blue', kde = True)

x1 = ax1.lines[0].get_xdata()
y1 = ax1.lines[0].get_ydata()
plt.axvline(x1[np.argmax(y1)], color='blue')

ax2 = sns.distplot(data02, color = 'red', kde = True)

x2 = ax2.lines[2].get_xdata() # <--- Use correct index 2 here
y2 = ax2.lines[2].get_ydata() # <--- Use correct index 2 here
plt.axvline(x2[np.argmax(y2)], color='red')

plt.legend()
```

[image]